# Answers unaccepted everyday around 1h30

Tags: discussion

Has someone encountered the same problem?

4 days in a row, unaccepted answers around 1h30 / 2h each time.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doesn't look like a bug in the system, more like... a few users unaccepting your answers at roughly the same time on different days.

Perhaps a [rather large country](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=01:45+UTC+in+India) wakes up around that time. This is nothing to worry about; you should work with the askers to fix your answers.

Comment: Mh this seemed too big to be a coincidence but I'm ready to believe it is. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @YassinHajaj [Improbable things happen](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Improbable_things_happen).